# TsConfig target getting ignored seemingly ignored

Tags: typescript, msbuild, tsconfig

I am trying to set up a ts config for a project, as we are a good deal of developers spread around different locations, and it would be nice to have a common compiler settings file, compared to everybody setting it in the .csproj.

I am having a bit of trouble with targeting es6, where it claims to be unable to find extensions such as endswith and startsWith, hopefully, someone here can point the error/problem.

[Image of the TsConfig, and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoxGz.png)

the msbuild seems to be the problem and targets Es5

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.3\tsc.exe  --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError --listEmittedFiles --locale en-US